# How to best iterate (breadth-first) over an lxml etree using Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to wrap my head around lxml (new to this) and how I can use it to do what I want to do.  I've got an well-formed and valid XML file

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b>Text</b>
    <c>More text</c>
  </a>
  <!-- some comment -->
  <a>
    <d id="10" />
  </a>
</root>
```

something like this.  Now I'd like to visit the children breadth-first, and the best I can come up with is something like this:

```
for e in xml.getroot()[0].itersiblings() :
    print(e.tag, e.attrib)
```

and then take it from there.  However, this gives me *all* elements including comments

```
a {}
<built-in function Comment> {}
a {}
```

How do I skip over comments?  Is there a better way to iterate over the direct children of a node?

In general, what are the recommendations to parse an XML tree vs. event-driven pull-parsing using, say, `iterparse()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for your case

```py
for child in doc.getroot().iterchildren("*"):
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

Comment: this is just giving me the first children of the root. how can i get all childs with BFS search?

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked over 9 years ago, but I just ran into this issue myself, and I solved it with the following

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = xmlfile.getroot()

visit = [root]
while len(visit):
  curr = visit.pop(0)
  print(curr.tag, curr.attrib, curr.text)
  visit += list(curr)
```

`list(node)` will give a list of all the *immediate* children of that node. So by adding those children to a stack and just repeating that process with whatever is on the top of the stack (popping it off at the same time), we should end up with a standard breadth-first search.